# need help on compiler errors

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EnemyMessage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter the code:");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int key;
        int i;
        String code = keyboard.next();
        for (key = 1; key <= 100; key++) {
            for (i = 0; i < code.length(); i--) {
                char c = code.charAt(i);
                int n = (int) c;
                System.out.println(n);
                {
                    (char) c = (int) c - 32 + key + 127;
                    System.out.println(c);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This block of code gives me two errors that don't make much sense to me. As far as I know, I didn't do anything different then what I have been doing before.

Errors:

1. misplaced constructor
2. {" expected

Comment: Add a language tag of java, so that others will know which language you're using at a glance.

Comment: Also, the errors we can't *see* make no sense to us. You'll have to copy-paste them if you want a decent answer.

Comment: @ExcelledProducts - That probably >>is<< the entire code.

Comment: @StephenC before it was not even code. it was just stuff that my eyes could not understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EnemyMessage
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("enter the code:");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        int key;
        int i;
        String code = keyboard.next();
        for (key = 1; key<=100; key++)
        {
        for ( i = 0; i < code.length(); i--)
        {
            char c = code.charAt(i);
            int n = (int)c;
            System.out.println(n);
            { 
            c = (char)(c - 32 + key + 127);
            System.out.println(c);
            }
        }

    }
   }
}
```

2)"{" expeceted means you are missing a {

1)misplaced constructor is caused because you don't have {

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, I don't see any code errors (or I didn't when I formatted with IntelliJ) except for this line:

```
(char) c = (int) c - 32 + key + 127;
```

You're casting something you want to store in a `char` to an `int`.  That's just not going to work.

Fix your cast to include the entire scope of what it is you want to cast.  The cast to `char` is redundant since `c` is a `char`.

```
c = (char) (c - 32 + key + 127);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems are caused by this:

```
    {
        (char) c = (int) c - 32 + key + 127;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
```

The `(char) c = ...;` is completely invalid syntax.

An assignment is supposed to look like this `c = ...;`.

If you want / need to do a type cast before assigning, the type cast belongs on the right hand side of the assignment operator; i.e. `c = (char)(...)`.

---

Anyway, what you have written has cause the Java parser (in your IDE) to get thoroughly confused ... and *spectacularly* misdiagnose the error as an attempt to declare a constructor, it the wrong context.

Unfortunately, this happens sometimes ... though it is compiler dependent.  The compiler was trying to be helpful, but the compiler / compiler writer "guessed wrong" about what you were trying to write at that point.

Then it appears that the compiler's syntax recovery has inserted a `{` symbol into its symbol stream in an attempt to fix things.  The second error complains that there is no `}` to match the phantom `{` that it inserted.  Again, it has guessed wrong.

But the root cause of this was your original syntax error.

---

For the record, the `int` cast in your original expression is not necessary.  You *could* (and IMO should) write the assignment as this:

```
c = (char) (c - 32 + key + 127);
```

**Explanation:** in Java, the arithmetic operators always promote their operands to `int` (or `long`) before performing the operation, and the result is an `int` (or `long`).  That means that your explicit cast of `c` to an `int` is going to happen anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Change the linke 
    (char)c = (int)c -32 + key + 127;
to
    c = (char) ((int) c - 32 + key + 127);

Comment: I don't think that such a casting cascade is a great idea in this case.

Comment: @Zegar - it is not necessary.  See the end of my answer.